# Live Unit testing is not working "Failed to initialize client proxy: could not connect to test process."

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, live-unit-tests

When Trying to activate live unit testing on VS 2017 I get this error:

```
 [TestRunner 1] Failed to initialize client proxy: could not connect to test process.
FatalError - System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestPlatformException: Failed to initialize client proxy: could not connect to test process.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyOperationManager.SetupChannel(IEnumerable`1 sources)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyExecutionManager.InitializeExtensions(IEnumerable`1 sources)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyExecutionManager.StartTestRun(TestRunCriteria testRunCriteria, ITestRunEventsHandler eventHandler)
```

Other similar solutions to this error say it might be permissions so I've already tried running VS2017 as administrator, but that didn't work. and other solutions say tat I need to run the test in a different way but this is for live unit testing so I don't think they a viable options. I've even created a new unit test project from the one that already existed but I still get this error.

Update:
The Tests are located in a MsTest V2 test project running on a VS2017 enterprise Edition and it is testing an MVC webpage project under .Net framework 4.5.2 using Git version controls.

Comment: what kind of units are you running?  MsTest, MsTest V2, nUnit, xUnit, etc? Do you try a repair on visual studio?  What version of Visual Studio 2017?  What type of project?

Comment: Try to use Live Unit Testing for the first time now and am getting the same error with VS 15.4, .NET 4.6.2, NUnit 3.8.1, and NUnit Test Adapter 3.8.0

Answer (score 1):

In my case issue was caused because of wrong configuration of my runsettings file.

If you use testsettings , try to execute tests without using it.